# I cant refer to const because "is not defined" but it is

Tags: javascript

I want to refer to const `game` in browser console, but it shout that `game` is not defined, but it is. I also can't refer to any of const that I declarated.

I was trying to use `let` or even `var` but problem still exist. This is the `online.js` file that i declarated in `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Multiply</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ver">version</div>
    <div class="wraper">
            <div class="submit">
                    <button type="submit" id="level">hard</button>
            </div>
        <div class="numbers" id="numbers">div</div>

        <div class="answer">
                <input type="tel" id="answer">
        </div>

        <div class="submit">
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Sprawdź!</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
    <script type="module" src="online.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import Game from '/Game.js';

const numbers = document.getElementById("numbers");
const answer = document.getElementById("answer");
const button = document.getElementById("submit");
const level = document.getElementById("level");
const ver = document.getElementById("ver");

const game = new Game();

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    game.pair.flag = true;
    numbers.innerText = game.writeNumbers();
    answer.focus();
})

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    game.checkAnswer(answer.value);
    console.log(game.numbers);

    numbers.innerText = game.writeNumbers();
})
```

So why `.addEventListener` can refer to that const but I cant?

Comment: because it's not exported I would say, it's just part of your `module` online.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables declared on the top level of modules do not implicitly get assigned to the global object by default. (This is arguably quite a good thing - scope control helps keep code maintainable.) If you want to create global variables referenceable from the console inside a module, you'll have to do so explicitly:

```
window.game = new Game();
```

(but you should only do this for debugging purposes, probably - once the script is working as desired, better to scope `game` just to the module again, and declare it with `const`)

Comment: Thats works! Thanks a lot! :)) Yes, i was only need this for debugging purposes :)